# Configure jetty context path with dynamic .war file name

Tags: jetty

Is it possible to deploy a .war file that has a different name on each deploy but configure a static context path?

I read through these docs : http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html but was unsure where which jetty xml config this would go in:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
     <Set name="contextPath">/test</Set>
</Configure>
```